# Emberjs: what's the context the classBinding on {{#view}} helper use?

Tags: ember.js, view-helpers

The [doc](http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_modifying-a-view-s-html)'s example implies that the `context` is the `instance` of a `View` without a `controller`. But I can't try this out with latest version, please check [this jsfiddle's link](http://jsfiddle.net/gqRmv/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I would do this: http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/ACqjt/1/

Just to clarify context of the view is set to it's controller by default. If you want to access a property of view such as `flag` inside the view template you would use `view.flag` to refer to it.

I prefer to setup view class name bindings inside the view itself:

```
classNameBindings: ['flag:A:B']
```

You should also be able to do the binding in the template, but I am not sure why that is not working in your fiddle. Do not use quotations when you are defining your view, instead use:

```
{{view App.CustomDiv}}
```

or

```
{{#view App.CustomDiv}}{{/view}}
```

if you dont want to use a seperate template for your view. I like to setup a template for each view I have. I put them in separate files for example `custom.handlebars`, but for demonstration in jsFiddle you can use the `data-template-name` property to name the template you want to use, and then refer to it inside the view definition using `templateName`. I hope this helps you move forward.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works that setup `classNameBindings` inside the `View`, but I think it could be more flexible that defining the binding in templates.