# treating the last element of a list differently in handlebars #each block

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a separator between elements in an {{#each}} loop except after the last element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403003/how-do-i-add-a-separator-between-elements-in-an-each-loop-except-after-the)

As a simplest case, lets say that I have a list of names and I want them to be displayed with commas between them. I could do

```
{{#each name in names }} {{name}}, {{/each}}
```

which would then produce the last

```
John, Paul, George, Ringo,
```

with a final comma that is not wanted. I can think of ways to handle this by adding the commas in my controller functions, but that seems awkward and kind of infringes on the MVC separation. Is there a way just in handlebars to identify when you're dealing with the last element and adjust accordingly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10403003/1032493

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a `.join` function which you most probably can use:

```
['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo'].join(', '); //John, Paul, George, Ringo
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way in case you are not able to use Join.

```
var arr = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo'];
var names="";
$.each(arr, function(i,val) { 

if (i < arr.length-1)
  names += val + ","
else
 names += val
 });
alert (names);
```