# Handlebar each helper

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I want to add _first = true to first object for all objects passed into the compilation.
_first = true should be added to both data and company for only first array.

Template

```
<script id="firsttemp" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

        {{#each objects}}
        <tr>

        <td class="tableFirstCol"><input type="checkbox" class="check" id="childcheck" /></td>
        <td class="tableFirstCol"><input type="checkbox" class="star" id="childstar" /></td>
        <td class="tableFirstCol"><input type="checkbox" class="alarm" id="childalarm" /></td>
        <td class="tableFirstCol">{{name}}<span>{{name}}</span></td>

        </tr>
        {{/each}}
</script>
```

Json

```
company =    {
            "name": "IBM",
            "lastprice": 310.2,
            "dayschange": 120.1,
            "dayshigh": 220.9,
            "volume": 140.3,
            "52weekhigh": 200.3,
            "name2": "herohonda",
            "dataset": [1200,2000,5200],
            "lastprice2": "1:10pm",
            "dayschange2": "8%",
            "dayshigh2": "1.5%",
            "volume2": "1:10 Pm",
            "52weekhigh2": "1:10 Pm"
        },
         {
            "name": "zbHero Honda",
            "lastprice": 310.2,
            "dayschange": 220.1,
            "dayshigh": 220.9,
            "volume": 140.3,
            "52weekhigh": 200.3,
            "name2": "herohonda",
            "dataset": [3200,3500,5000],
             "dataset1":[20,+54,1000],
            "lastprice2": "1:10pm",
            "dayschange2": "8%",
            "dayshigh2": "1.5%",
            "volume2": "1:10 Pm",
            "52weekhigh2": "1:10 Pm"
        }
```

complation:

```
$("#row-2-td-1-table").html( template({objects:company}) );  
$("#row-2-td-1-table").html( template({objects:data}) );
```

Result Should be:

```
company =    {
            "_first" : true,
            "name": "IBM",
            "lastprice": 310.2,
            "dayschange": 120.1,
            "dayshigh": 220.9,
            "volume": 140.3,
            "52weekhigh": 200.3,
            "name2": "herohonda",
            "dataset": [1200,2000,5200],
            "lastprice2": "1:10pm",
            "dayschange2": "8%",
            "dayshigh2": "1.5%",
            "volume2": "1:10 Pm",
            "52weekhigh2": "1:10 Pm"
        },
         {
            "name": "zbHero Honda",
            "lastprice": 310.2,
            "dayschange": 220.1,
            "dayshigh": 220.9,
            "volume": 140.3,
            "52weekhigh": 200.3,
            "name2": "herohonda",
            "dataset": [3200,3500,5000],
             "dataset1":[20,+54,1000],
            "lastprice2": "1:10pm",
            "dayschange2": "8%",
            "dayshigh2": "1.5%",
            "volume2": "1:10 Pm",
            "52weekhigh2": "1:10 Pm"
        }
```

Comment: There's some discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479094/conditional-on-last-item-in-array-using-handlebars-js-template which might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template:

```
<tr  {{#equal @index}}{{/equal}}>
</tr>
```

Regitry Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('equal', function(lvalue, options) {

    if( lvalue==0 ) {
        return "id=firstTr-1";
    } 
});
```