# How to access final element in Handlebars.js array?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

Given the following data structure:

```
{
    "name" : "test",
    "assetType" : "Home",
    "value" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "999",
            "date" : "10/03/2018"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "1234.56",
            "date" : "10/04/2018"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I directly access the first and last element of `value` in Handlebars? My code is:

```
<td>{{value.[0].value}}</td>
<td>{{value.[value.length - 1].value}}</td>
```

The first statement works fine, but I cannot figure out how to access the last element. `value.length` inside the `[]`'s does not return any value, but rendering `value.length` outside of the array works fine.

I tried using `@first` and `@last` in the array but those don't seem to work either.

Comment: You need to create a helper function. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479094/conditional-on-last-item-in-array-using-handlebars-js-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out, you can easily solve this with a [template helper](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-helpers):

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  first (arr) {
    return arr && arr[0]
  },
  last (arr) {
    return arr && arr[arr.length - 1]
  },
  atIndex (arr, index) {
    return arr && index >= 0 && index <= arr.length - 1 && arr[index]
  }
})
```

You can then create a [context](http://blazejs.org/api/blaze.html#Blaze-With) using `#with` where the context object is the result of the helpers. Inside this context you can access properties using `this`.

Accessing values with the name `value` would look like the following:

```js
<td>{{#with first value}}{{this.value}}{{/with}}</td>
<td>{{#with last value}}{{this.value}}{{/with}}</td>
<td>{{#with atIndex value 5}}{{this.value}}{{/with}}</td>
```