# Determining the last loop index in ractive template

Tags: ractivejs

Basically I want to this: [In Mustache templating is there an elegant way of expressing a comma separated list without the trailing comma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114435/in-mustache-templating-is-there-an-elegant-way-of-expressing-a-comma-seperated-l) in a Ractive template.

For the object

```
{
  "items": [
    {"name": "red"},
    {"name": "green"},
    {"name": "blue"}
  ]
}
```

I want to produce "red, green, blue"
I want to know if I am at the last item, so I can know whether to print the separator. Something like:

```
{{#items:i}}{{name}} {{#i.is_last}},{{/i}}{{/items}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't easily test this right now, but wouldn't something like the following work?

```
{{#items:i}}
    {{name}} {{ i < (items.length-1) ? "," : "" }}
{{/items}}
```

Comment: Cool but if I wanted not a comma, but an HTML element, this wouldn't be too good right?

Comment: I don't like have too much nesting. What if I have a string within the html element? Then I would have a string within an html element within a string within a mustache template!

Answer (score 2):

Can confirm that Stephen Thomas' answer works. Another option would be to join the array items like so:

```js
ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'body',
  template: '{{ items.map( getName ).join( ", " ) }}',
  data: {
    items: [{ name: 'red' }, { name: 'green' }, { name: 'blue' }],
    getName: function ( item ) {
      return item.name;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually wanted a solution that would allow me to put something more complicated instead of a comma, say, a DOM element. I figured out (another) method that works.

```
{{#items:i}}
  {{name}}{{#(i<(items.length-1))}}, {{/end}}
{{/items}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently `@index` and `@last` magic variables are introduced, so the example now becomes more readable:

```
{{#items}}
  {{.name}}{{#@index !== @last}}, {{/}}
{{/}}
```