# JSON to JSON mapping using Mustache

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

I want to map my Input JSON with another JSON using `mustache`.

My Input JSON is like:

```
{
  "data": [
    { "catalogId": "1850", "productId": "ELEC004A"},
    { "catalogId": "1851", "productId": "PNG679"}
  ]
}
```

I want a template in which I could combine the mustache tags with my output json.

```
var template = JSON.stringify(
  {
    Product: [
      {{#data}}
      {
        productId:'{{productId}}',
        parentProductId:'{{catalogId}}'
      }
      {{/data}} 
    ]
  }
);
```

I tried this but using mustache tag with JSON are giving me errors.
I tried defining the template without using `JSON.stringify` but no luck!

Have to use mustache only as it is the requirement, the actual input JSON is quite large and can't map it using the traditional way.

Comment: What is your desired output? and why moustache? why not just regular javascript code?

Comment: You might want to check your code formatting.

Comment: @TamasHegedus My desired output is a JSON mentioned in the template with mustache tags replaced with relevant data from my input JSON

Comment: To my understanding the argument you pass to JSON.stringify() is interpreted as an Object but contains mustache tags (such as {{#data}}). That results in incorrect JSON syntax.
Convert the template to a string and do not use JSON.stringify()

Comment: @StefanReimers yes you are right! But even if I remove stringify and do  a normal toString I get `unexpected token { on {{#data}}`

Comment: Maybe this might help:
var template = `
  {
    Product: [
      {{#data}}
      {
        productId:'{{productId}}',
        parentProductId:'{{catalogId}}'
      }
      {{/data}} 
    ]
  }`;

Answer (score 0):

> My desired output is a JSON mentioned in the template with mustache tags replaced with relevant data from my input JSON

You don't need moustache here.

```js
var input = {
  "data": [
    { "catalogId": "1850", "productId": "ELEC004A"},
    { "catalogId": "1851", "productId": "PNG679"}
  ]
};

var output = {
  Product: input.data.map(item => ({
    productId: item.productId,
    parentProductId: item.catalogId
  }))
};

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I need to do it using mustache only, This is just a sample JSON my actual JSON is pretty large can't map it using the traditional technique.

Comment: I'm afraid that's the harder way to do, and more error prone. Lets see what can we do about it

Comment: @Abhishek Moustache is not capable of this. You cannot generate for example comma separated lists. All you are going to end up with is 50% boilerplate and workaround code besides the template. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114435/in-mustache-templating-is-there-an-elegant-way-of-expressing-a-comma-seperated-l