# How to render a JSON template using mustache

Tags: json, mustache

I'm trying to generate a JSON file with mustache with the following template:

```
{
    "name": "{{customer_info.first_name}}",
    "email": "{{contact_info.email}}",
    "campaign": {
        "campaignId": "{{contact_info.campaign.campaignId}}"
    },
    "tags": [
        {{#contact_info.tags}} 
        {
            "tagId": "{{tagId}}"
        },
        {{/contact_info.tags}}
    ]
}
```

As an output example I get:

```
{
    "name": "Antonio",
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "campaign": {
        "campaignId": "pfft"
    },
    "tags": [
        {
            "tagId": "6prrtAP"
        },
        {
            "tagId": "64rrrE9"
        },
    ]
}
```

Which unluckily is a BAD FORMATTED JSON, because there is a not wanted "," after the last element in the array.

Can any of you help me in solving this issue and remove the comma ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Generating JSON from textual template sounds like a very bad idea to me.

Comment: Totally aggree with @el.pescado-нетвойне. Why wouldn't you just generate your object and just serialize to JSON?

Answer (score 3):

I would do this:

```
var md = {};
var tagsCount = 2;
var currTagIndex = 0;
md['show_comma'] = function(){
    currTagIndex++;
    return currTagIndex <= tagsCount;
}
```

Then in Mustache template:

```
{{#show_comma}}
,
{{/show_comma}}
```

Comment: This solution assumes JavaScript as the host language and it might not be portable to every other host language. Still an elegant solution, though!

Answer (score 2):

Don't generate JSON from textual templates. You'll constantly face problems like this. Superfluous commas, meta characters in strings (what if `customer_info.first_name` contains double quotes), failing to properly nest structures etc.

Generate your data as native structures in your programming language, and encode it as JSON using library provided by your programming language.

---

However, if you absolutely need, try to generate as much JSON data as possible (ideally, self-contained JSON fragment) outside template, and interpolate that inside template. For example:

```
let contact_info = {"tags": [ "6prrtAP", "64rrrE9" ]}
let tags = contact_info.tags.map((tag) => ({"tagId": tag})); // [{tagId: "6prrtAP"}, {tagId: "64rrrE9"}]
let tagsJSON = JSON.stringify(tags); // "[{\"tagId\":\"6prrtAP\"},{\"tagId\":\"64rrrE9\"}]"
```

Then, pass `tagsJSON` to your template:

```
{
    "name": "{{customer_info.first_name}}",
    "email": "{{contact_info.email}}",
    "campaign": {
        "campaignId": "{{contact_info.campaign.campaignId}}"
    },
    "tags": {{tagsJSON}}
}
```

That way, `tagsJSON` always contains valid JSON-encoded data, so it might be safely interpolated as a value in JSON dictionary/object. Even if tag list is empty, even if tag IDs suddenly start to contain characters that need escaping etc. All corner cases are already handled for you.

Comment: He didn't ask for a lecture. Sometimes it makes sense to use a template if you know only a very small, controllable portion of the code is going to change. Or you've inherited it from someone else and can't re-engineer it. You don't even attempt an actual solution, I'm not sure why this got upvoted at all.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I've edited my answer to include an actual solution.

Comment: maybe you can use [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/) ... it helps doing things like this:
if you have let contact_info = {"tags": [ "6prrtAP", "64rrrE9" ]}
then you can do something like this: `jq '.tags[] | {tagid:.}'` it's a command line tool but there are libraries for it in many languages

Answer (score 2):

Try using [SelectTransform](https://selecttransform.github.io/site/) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stjs) package. It has Mustache like syntax without all the side-effects that Mustache creates and the package size is also not as heavy as Handlebars.js

```
import ST from "stjs";
 
const data = {
  name: 'Jakub',
  friends: [
    {
      name: 'Michal'
    }
  ]
};
 
const template = {
  newName: '{{ name }}',
  friends: {
    '{{ #each friends }}': {
      subName: '{{ name }}'
    }
  }
};
 
console.log(ST.select(data).transformWith(template).root());
 
// Result:
/**
 * {
 *   "newName": "Jakub",
 *   "friends": [
 *     {
 *       "subName": "Michal"
 *     }
 *   ]
 * }
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing some similar problem and I found out that [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) is a lot similar to mustache and way more powerful.

You could check that out and try using this template to solve your problem, without adding anything to your current model.

```
{
    "name": "{{customer_info.first_name}}",
    "email": "{{contact_info.email}}",
    "campaign": {
        "campaignId": "{{contact_info.campaign.campaignId}}"
    },
    "tags": [
        {{#each contact_info.tags}} 
        {
            "tagId": "{{tagId}}"
        }{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}
        {{/each}}
    ]
}
```

Comment: True, but then. Moustache is 110kb as of now. Handlebars is 2.7mb! choose wisely.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good answer:

```
contact_info['tags'][ contact_info['tags'].length - 1 ].last = true;
```

and the template would be

```
{{#contact_info.tags}} 
{
   "tagId": "{{tagId}}"
} {{^last}}, {{/last}}
{{/contact_info.tags}}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7591866